# "Too many open files" error when opening and loading images in Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When running the following code:

```
KEEP=[]
for file in glob.glob("./KEEP/thing*.[tT][iI][fF]"):
    m = pattern.search(file)
    filename=m.group(1)
    keep=Image.open(file)
    keep.load()
    KEEP.append(keep)
    KEEP_NAMES.append(filename)
    keep.close()
```

over more than a thousand files, I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/hom/yannis/texmf/python/remove-harakat.py", line 123, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2237, in open
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: './KEEP/thing1118_26.TIF'
```

I don't understand why this is happening, since I'm load()ing and then close()ing all files, why should they remain open?
Is there a solution to this problem, other than reducing the number of files (which is not an option for me)? Some way to close them after their contents have been read in memory?

Comment: Unable to reproduce with Python 3 and latest Pillow. @yannis, please try to run this script http://pastebin.com/tP6E3UXE - does the problem reproduce?

Comment: `keep.close()` should be totally unnecessary since `keep.load()` [should be loading the file data and then discarding the file object in the background](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.close). Maybe it is having some side effect? I am still working on reproducing the error but try just removing the close and see if that helps.

Comment: Also unable to reproduce with 4000 images in Python 2.7.8 or 3.4.1 and PILLOW 2.7.0. Are you sure this is the actual code that dies? I wonder if maybe you are opening the file yourself, providing the file object (not the path) to PIL and then accidentally closing the *Image* instead of the *FIle Object* ...? I actually tried that but haven't been able to hit the open file limit yet.

Comment: Which version of Pillow? What OS? If this can be reproduced, please open an issue over here: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/new

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by executing ulimit -n 2048 on the shell (it was 1024, and this is exactly the number of files that pillow managed to open before crashing)

Comment: I ran alexanderlukanin13's script and it didn't crashed. If there is some way to send you a personal message, I will send you the script file and the images, to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 18):

This may be a bug with the `Image.load` method - see [Pillow issue #1144](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1144). I ran into the same `too many open files` error - see [#1237](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1237).

My work-around was to load the image into a temp object, make a copy, and then explicitly close the temp. For your code it would look something like this:

```
KEEP=[]
for file in glob.glob("./KEEP/thing*.[tT][iI][fF]"):
    m = pattern.search(file)
    filename = m.group(1)
    temp = Image.open(file)
    keep = temp.copy()
    KEEP.append(keep)
    KEEP_NAMES.append(filename)
    temp.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

I also ran into this issue and resolved the issue with a slightly different approach.

This workaround uses `copy.deepcopy()`, which is based on similar logic of @indirectlylit's solution but avoids creating of `temp`. See code snippet below

```py
import copy

KEEP=[]
for file in glob.glob("./KEEP/thing*.[tT][iI][fF]"):
    m = pattern.search(file)
    filename = m.group(1)
    keep = copy.deepcopy(Image.open(file))
    KEEP.append(keep)
    KEEP_NAMES.append(filename)
```