# load all the images from a directory, but too many open files

Tags: python

I have more than 1,000 JPEG images in my current directory.
First I am trying to save them as a list of images and then convert the list into 4d ndarray. I am geting

> [Errno 24] Too many open files:

```
image_list = []
filename = 'data/training_images/'
for filename in glob.glob('data/training_images/*.jpg'):
    im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
#  convert list of images into 4d ndarray: numOfImages x height x width x channel
```

How do I fix this issue? Are there simpler alternatives?

Comment: try close the file after image_list.append(im)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29234413/too-many-open-files-error-when-opening-and-loading-images-in-pillow#

Comment: `Image.open` ... is what? Are you using an imaging package? If so, include that in the tags and an `import` in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
image_list = []
filename = 'data/training_images/'
for filename in glob.glob('data/training_images/*.jpg'):
    im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
    im.close()
```

This will close each file after you have appended the image to your list.